# How to stream a complex video to YouTube using ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming, youtube, video-streaming

I have a video that I'd like to stream live on YouTube using ffmpeg. The video has no audio, but rather busy visuals (lots of rapidly changing colors). I'm trying to stream at 720p, but whenever I watch the live stream, it's not smooth. There's lots of stutters and buffering. However, after the live stream is over and I watch the no-longer-live video, all the frames are present and smooth.

This initially made me think I just had issues viewing live streaming, but I have no trouble watching other 720p or higher streams. Furthermore, when streaming the complex parts of my video the ffmpeg "time=..." slows down, the bitrate shoots up, and the fps also drops.

This makes me believe that the issue is with the ffmpeg command I'm using to send it. When I use the same command to send a simpler video (all white with a black frame), I don't have any issues.

Here's my ffmpeg script:

```
INPUT=""
# Read input as native framerate
INPUT="$INPUT -re"
# Input file
INPUT="$INPUT -i input.flv"

AUDIO=""
# Read input as native framerate
AUDIO="$AUDIO -re"
# Audio codec (lavfi is better for bandwidth?)
AUDIO="$AUDIO -f lavfi"
# Input (dummy)
AUDIO="$AUDIO -i aevalsrc=0"

OUTPUT=""
# Video codec
OUTPUT="$OUTPUT -c:v libx264"
# Video resolution
OUTPUT="$OUTPUT -video_size 1280x720"
# Pixel format
#OUTPUT="$OUTPUT -pix_fmt yuv420p"
# Attempt to force bitrate at 1500k
OUTPUT="$OUTPUT -minrate 150k -maxrate 150k -b:v 150k"
# frames per second
OUTPUT="$OUTPUT -r 25"
# Audio codec
OUTPUT="$OUTPUT -c:a libvo_aacenc"
# GOP size (calculates intraframes)
OUTPUT="$OUTPUT -g 30"
# Format
OUTPUT="$OUTPUT -f flv"
# Allow use of "experimental" encoders
OUTPUT="$OUTPUT -strict experimental"
# Testing
OUTPUT="$OUTPUT rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/xxx"
```

Is it possible to use ffmpeg to send this sort of video without buffering?